# Parse Date from HTML Conditional Get Header

Tags: java, date, http-headers, spring-3

I am working with spring and trying to parse a http header date in the common rfc format:
"Sat, 29 Oct 2011 19:43:31 GMT"

The problem is, that my DateFormatter can't parse it:

Unparseable date: "Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT"

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date lastModifiedDate;
try {
    lastModifiedDate = formatter.parse(lastModified);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

It's very confusing, that on my developer machine everything works fine so far, but on the server the unparsable date exception occurs.

I've tried DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG).parse(lastModified); as well, but without any effort

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

29 Oct 2012 is a Monday, not a Saturday.

Comment: Thanks, that was caused by testing some values! Unparseable date: "Wed, 23 Nov 2011 9:14:31 GMT" doesn't work either